# Spark streaming - transform two streams and join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scala-collections

I've got an issue where I need to transform two streams am reading from spark before joining.

Once I do the transformation, I no longer can join, I guess the type is no longer DStream[(String, String)] but DStream[Map[String, String]]

```
val windowStream1 = act1Stream.window(Seconds(5)).transform{rdd => rdd.map(_._2).map(l =>(...toMap)}
val windowStream2 = act2Stream.window(Seconds(5)).transform{rdd => rdd.map(_._2).map(l =>(...toMap)}

val joinedWindow = windowStream1.join(windowStream2)  //can't join
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your problem but makes it more digestible. You can split up the method chain and document which types you would expect on each step by defining temporal val/def/var identifiers with the expected type. This way you can easily spot where the type is not matching your expectations anymore.

E.g. I expect your `act1Stream` and `act2Stream` instances to be of type `DStream[(String, String)]`, which i will call `s1` and `s2` for the moment. Comment me if that is not the case.

```
def joinedWindow(
      s1: DStream[(String, String)], 
      s2: DStream[(String, String)]
    ): DStream[...] = {
  val w1 = windowedStream(s1)
  val w2 = windowedStream(s2)
  w1.join(w2)
}
def windowedStream(actStream: DStream[(String, String)]): DStream[Map[...]] = {
  val windowed: DStream[(String, String)] = actStream.window(Seconds(5))
  windowed.transform( myTransform )
}
def myTransform(rdd: RDD[(String, String)]): RDD[Map[...]] = {
  val mapped: RDD[String] = rdd.map(_._2)
  // not enough information to conclude 
  // the result type from given code
  mapped.map(l =>(...toMap)) 
}
```

From there one can conclude the rest of the types by filling the `...` sections. Line by line eliminating compiler errors until you get your desired results. With the documentation of

[`DStream[T]`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)

- `def window(windowDuration: Duration): DStream[T]`
- `def transform[U](transformFunc: (RDD[T]) ⇒ RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): DStream[U]`

[`PairDStreamFunctions[K,V]`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions)

- `def join[W](other: DStream[(K, W)])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[W]): DStream[(K, (V, W))]`

[`RDD[T]`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

- `def map[U](f: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]`

At least this way you get to the point where you exactly know that the expected type and the produced type do not match.

Comment: Yes, `act1Stream` and `act2Stream` are of type `DStream[Map[String, String]]` but let me explain here. I have two different streams of type `DStream[(String, String)]` but before joining, I need to transform each stream and the transform method returns a `DStream[Map[String, String]]` and can't join it...so is there a way to join two streams `DStream[Map[String, string]]`

Comment: I am no spark expert, but it seems that the join operation is only defined on `PairDStreamFunctions[K,V]`s. The signature tells me that you require to have two instance of type `DStream[(K,V)]` in order to be able to apply the join operation. Maybe you can somehow morph your `transform` and inner `map`s to return `DStream[(String,Map[String,String])]` instances, if that makes sense in your use case somehow...